# How to handle date and time to convert to TimeStamp format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, timestamp

I need to be able to convert to DateTime format a date and time like the following: '**08/23/2023 09:30:00**'
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const dateTimeString = '08/23/2023 09:30:00';
const [datePart, timePart] = dateTimeString.split(' ');

const [month, day, year] = datePart.split('/');
const [hour, minute, second] = timePart.split(':');

const formattedDateString = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:${second}`;
const dateTimeObject = new Date(formattedDateString);

console.log(dateTimeObject); // Output: Wed Aug 23 2023 09:30:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

--- Edit ---

```
const date = new Date('08/23/2023 10:30:00');

const options = {
  timeZone: 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric',
};

const formattedTime = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date);
console.log(formattedTime); // Output: 10:30:00
```

This should work, quick advice when asking questions try to give some code to better clarify what you are trying to achieve. Also i got the answer in 2 second just by asking Chat-GPT i advise you to use it when in need of chucks of code

Comment: It works perfectly, but in Argentina we have GMT-3. Is there a way to avoid this correction and if the time is 10:30:00 it shows me that time and not 13:30:00

Comment: Sorry the format time here is  '23/08/2023 09:30:00 not '08/23/2023 09:30:00'

Comment: I expressed myself wrong, what I need is to convert to TimeStamp '08/25/23 10:30:00' but not apply GMT-3

Comment: The first approach work fine, in the next line add Z for GMT Zone and solved. const formattedDateString = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:${second}Z`; Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Parsing a string to make another string for the built–in parser doesn't make sense. Once you have the parts, just pass them directly to the Date constructor: `new Date(year, month-1, day, hour, minute, second).getTime()`. To treat the values as UTC, use `Date.UTC(year, month-1, ...)` (which returns a time value, not a Date but wrapping it in `new Date(...)` returns a Date).